# Examples for writing a daemon or a service in Linux

Tags: python, c, linux, process, daemon

I have been looking at daemons for Linux such as `httpd` and have also looked at some code that can be used as a skeleton. I have done a fair amount of research and now I want to practice writing it. However, I'm not sure of what can I use a daemon for. Any good examples/ideas that I can try to execute?

I was thinking of using a daemon along with libnotify on Ubuntu to have pop-up notifications of select tweets.

1. Is this a bad example for implementing a daemon?
2. Will you even need a daemon for this?
3. Can this be implemented as a service rather than a daemon?

Comment: A helpful function is: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html

Comment: Daemon, service, background task ... just names ... - what do really want to do?

Comment: @alk I just want to write my own daemon script just to practice and learn more. But I can't think of any idea. The best I could think of was the one I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Shivaji_Vidhale: It's hard to think of a _practical_ idea, but for a toy… what about a logger daemon similar to `syslogd`, which listens for messages on a UDP port and writes them to a file? Of course you already have a better `syslogd`, and if you really needed to write one you could `inetd`-ify it and not have to worry about daemonizing or listening on a socket, and so on, but it should be something you can write in about 20 lines of code and play with. And, unlike your idea, it doesn't require interacting with the GUI, which can be tricky for a daemon.

Answer (score 1):

First: [PEP 3143](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/) tries to enumerate all of the fiddly details you have to get right to write a daemon in Python. And it specifies a library that takes care of those details for you.

The PEP was deferred—at least in part because the community felt it was more a responsibility of POSIX or some Linux standards group or something to first define exactly what is essential to being a daemon, before Python could have its own position on how to implement one. But it's still a great guide. However, the reference implementation of that proposed library still lives on, as [`python-daemon`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/), which you can install from PyPI.

---

Meanwhile, the really interesting question for this project isn't so much service vs. daemon, as root vs. user. Do you want a single process that keeps track of all users' twitter accounts, and sends notifications to anyone who's logged in? Just a per-user process? Or maybe both, a single process watching all the tweets, then sending notifications via user processes?

Of course you don't really need a daemon or service for this. For example, it could be a GUI app whose main window is a configuration dialog, which keeps running (maybe with a traybar thingy) even when you close the config dialog, and it would work just as well. The question isn't whether you *need* a daemon, but whether it's *more appropriate*. Which really is a design choice.

Comment: Alright, but all I wanted to do is practice writing daemon script or a server side component for Linux. I see stuff about HowTo but nothing gives me any idea to start working on. Can you think of any example that would help me gain more insight into writing scripts for Linux? Any beginner level  experiment that I can carry out?